# Blazemeter - Converting request stats into Second

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter, taurus

How can I fetch Stats in the Second format instead of Millisecond?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Divide stats by 1000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) - it will become seconds.

You can also download metrics in CSV format

[image]

and once done use [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) or [Microsoft Excel](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx) or equivalent in order to perform the conversion.

However be aware that it will lead to precision loss as 1499 ms will be rounded to 1 and 1501 ms will be rounded to 2 which is a huge difference in performance testing world.

You can reach out to [BlazeMeter Support](https://www.blazemeter.com/support) - they should have more information regarding their product features and roadmap than anyone here, they should also be able to implement feature on-demand